# Hop count - what will happen in this simple case

Tags: networking, routing

Consider ABCD

router A wants to send to D

It keeps hop count 3

What will be the HOP COUNT when the packet reaches D

Will it be zero or one?

Comment: hmm... three different answers to a universal standard situation, ammazed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B will decrement it from 3 to 2, and C will decrement it from 2 to 1. Therefore it will be 1 when it reaches D.

Comment: so what if D has to forward this packet, can it??

Comment: IF the TTL is 1 at D it will not forward it.

Answer (score 0):

D will forward it.  The node on the receiving end, say E, will drop it if it can't process it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, a ping is being sent from router A with a TTL of 3.  In that case it will not reach D. (I could be wrong, but it depends on how the router OS defines traversing)

```
a       b       c       d   
3   2   2   1   1 not forwarded by c
```

If a were a PC then

```
a       b       c           d   
3   3   3   2   2   1       1
```

edit - To determine how Router A defines "traversing" ping Router B from A with a TTL of 1.  My home routers do not correctly decrement the TTL so I can't test here.

Comment: I found this, "As insurance against this outcome, the TTL value of an IP datagram is decremented by a value of one each time the packet is forwarded by a network device. Thus, an IP packet can never be forwarded more than 254 times, preventing the infinite packet loop problem."  here http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/ttl-expiry.html